# How to build v8 dynamic libraries under Windows and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, v8

I've been able to build v8 successfully under **Windows 8.1** and **Visual Studio 2015 Update 2** with the build chain based on `GN` [Building with GN](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-GN) but I can't find how to build the v8 library. Basically I want to enable `component=shared_library` but I can't find how to do it...

Examples such as *helloworld.exe* are compiling and are working.

Here is how I built it so far:

```
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
mkdir depot_tools
cd depot_tools
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra/depot_tools.zip
cmake -E tar xf "depot_tools.zip" --format=zip
SET PATH=%CD%;%CD%\python276_bin;%PATH%
cd ..
gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
gclient sync
cd v8
python tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

I've also tried the old fashion way using `gyp` without success (does not compile):

```
SET DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
mkdir depot_tools
cd depot_tools
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-infra/depot_tools.zip
cmake -E tar xf "depot_tools.zip" --format=zip
SET PATH=%CD%;%CD%\python276_bin;%PATH%
cd ..
gclient config https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
set GYP_GENERATORS=ninja
gclient sync
cd v8
python gypfiles\gyp_v8 -Dtarget_arch=x64 -Dcomponent=shared_library
ninja -C out\Release_x64 all
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem, the solution is to edit the gn arguments.

after:

`python tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release`

just edit the file *out.gn/x64.release/args.gn* and add the line:

`is_component_build = true`

and after building you should find a v8.dll in your *out.gn/x64.release* folder.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to generate the v8.dll since but now all other static libraries needed under Windows are not generated (v8_libplatform, v8_libbase, ...), I have to link all the obj files. Do you also fixed that issues? PS: you can give args to gn in the command line `gn gen --args="is_debug=false is_component_build=true target_cpu=\"x64\"" out.gn/x64.release`

Comment: unfortanly not, if yout look in the file *out.gn/x64.release/obj/d8.ninja*, which is the v8 console, you will find every object file and library needed, in my project i just added all libraries and object files to the linker, and BOOM a running program with v8 script engine

Answer (score 0):

I was produced in a gyp. No that was the setting in the '`set GYP_GENERATORS = ninja`', was the setting in '`GYP_GENERATORS = msvs`'. Run the generated sln file, but leave some errors at the time of build, was successful build and browse the Internet.

Comment: Thank you, I made some progress by using `GYP_GENERATORS = msvs` but still not all target are linking, especially not the one I want (libv8.dll)...

The visual is trying to link `v8_base_0.lib` while `v8_base.lib` is actually the one built...


`30>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Y:\Sources\git.corp.adobe.com\Horizon\build\win64\lib-v8\v8\build\Release\lib\v8_base_0.lib'`
`41>------ Build started: Project: All, Configuration: Release x64 ------
========== Build: 21 succeeded, 20 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Do you not exist `libv8.dll` file? I also `libv8.dll` do not have. Error came out when trying to I build. However, it was possible to resolve the Internet search. I'm sorry if it is not a clear answer. For your error, please try to see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6b12xkc.aspx).